# Access data from Varien_Simplexml_Element Object

Tags: xml, magento

I am using below object.

```
$xmlElement = 

    Varien_Simplexml_Element Object
    (
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Varien_Simplexml_Element Object
                    (
                        [value] => 56319509
                    )

                [1] => Varien_Simplexml_Element Object
                    (
                        [value] => 56319510
                    )

            )

    )
```

But I am not able to access both values. I can get only one value using below code

```
$xmlElement->asArray();
```

How can I access both values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. I can access both values by converting it into array using below code

```
$datasArray =  get_object_vars($xmlElement);
```